# Service in different process

Tags: android

My app displays lots of image and cache them in memory so it uses lot's of memory (near 40MB heap size). On the other hand it downloads large 7zip file (300MB) and extract them using native code which uses lots of memory and processing. Sometimes extraction can't be done, but after app process restart it works. Although I don't get any exception as it's native code, I believe it's because of lack of memory.

So I decided to put the extraction in different process so I can kill it after it's done (Here the cost of new process is not a matter because first the job is more important and extraction is heavy processor consuming by itself). But now I before killing the process I must check if another extraction isn't started. Two solution came in my mind:

1- Start a whole new process for each extraction. (I don't know if it's possible in android)

2- Somehow check if another extraction isn't started and if not kill the process. (It may cause out of memory again)

3- Somehow wait for the extraction to complete before starting a new one. (it's very complicated as it must be done between different process)

As I can't figure out how to do this, I really need experts advises.

--EDIT-----------------------------------------------

I checked extracting a 400MB 7zip file. After first extract it always fails. So the process must be killed after each extraction and a new one start. So the second option is off the list!

And for the record, The native 7zip code is not mine, it's Andro7Z based on 7ZA of linux and even if I had compiled it myself but I don't really want to mess with it.

Comment: You can put the extraction service in a separate process, but why would you need to kill it when it is done? If you have programmed this properly, it should be able to reclaim all the memory that it used. If not, you need to fix that - not look for way to work around leaky code. How many users want some leaky memory-hog on their phone?

Comment: @DavidWasser Actually 7zip native code is not mine. It's Andro7z which is based on 7za of linux. And I prefer to kills it afterward so the memory is reclaimed totally. I didn't check it yet, but what if the second extract don't get enough memory. On the other hand this is my last and most reliable option because there won't be so two or more extraction in one time.

Comment: Either you aren't calling the correct methods in the library to free up the memory or the library has memory leaks. You should talk to the people who created the library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really must...you can put your extraction inside a `Service`, put the `Service` in a separate process.

You allow only a single extraction to occur at one time (you can control this yourself). If you use `startService()` to start an extraction, Android will ensure that you only ever have one `Service` instance running. In `onStartCommand()` you should check if you already have an extraction going on, if so you can refuse the request or queue it in a database or whatever. If not, you start a new Thread to do the extraction.

Once the extraction is complete the process can kill itself. The next attempt to extract (using `startService()`) will result in Android creating a new process and starting a new instance of the `Service`.

Comment: What if it's done in an IntentService? Is IntentService limited to one instance or can be more?

Comment: Another question, Is there any way to check if service is running and wait somehow till it's finished before sending new intent?

Comment: All Android services exist once only. Android manages that for you.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. IntentService queues the requests. Please read my edit. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use `ActivityManager.getRunningServices()` to check if your service is running. However, this isn't really a good way to do it (the documentation discourages using this for non-debug purposes). Another option would be to bind to the service and ask it if it is busy.

Comment: What about checking if extract process is running and if not start the service and if it's running sleep for one second and check again. I really need your advise. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do that using `ActivityManager.getRunningServices()`. It isn't recommended but should work for your purposes.

Comment: I believe you mean getRunningAppProcesses(). Why it's not recommended and docs discourage using it?

Comment: No, I meant `ActivityManager.getRunningServices()`. You can use that to see if your `Service` is running by just checking each returned object's `service` field. `getRunningAppProcesses()` could also be used but it is probably more work to figure out which process has your `Service` in it. The Android developers don't want apps using these methods (for some reason). But they do work, so you can use them.

Comment: How about using a lock and sending a broadcast when the service is finished so the lock is released?

Comment: I wonder why there is no way to define process on the fly in android!

Comment: Android is a framework for application components. It controls OS processes itself. There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach. When programming for Android I've found it is best not to ask such questions. Just learn to live with what you've got and try not to question the reasons behind the design decisions. Otherwise you'll go insane :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you trying to extract some file. I will regard only the Android code, the  extractor code may contain memory leaks.

But you could use the AsyncTask class to put this process in background and receive a callback once it's finished. Also if you need to keep track of your extract tasks, you can also use a list of instances of your task, this way you can control them, and know exactly how many still running, or cancel them.

So, I would create something like:

ExtractTaskController -  Responsible for creating, managing and holding the references to the task.
ExtractAsyncTask - Extending the AsyncTask class, and performing the actual extracting.

Comment: The type of file is 7Z and android doesn't support them. The files are large so java 7Z can't extract them. So it must be done using native code.

Comment: @Ali as I told, you can put this native calls inside an AsyncTask, after it finishes, you can deallocacte your used resources. If want to do one at a time, you can also implement a stack in the controller.

Comment: I don't have control over the native library and so I can't deallocacte resources. So I decided to put in different process.

Comment: An AsyncTask have a well defined life cycle, it will spawn a different process, do the task, do the clean (setting instances to null, closing socket and stuff), and die

Comment: AsyncTask run on the same process of the app, it runs in different thread.

Comment: You are right, I messed up thread and process. Have you tried putting it in a different thread and setting the instances to null, after the thread finished?

Comment: That doesn't free resources, the only way to reclaim total memory is killing the process!

Comment: OP is using a native (C-code) library that seems to have memory leaks. He needs to kill the entire OS process after the extraction is complete because the library doesn't clean itself up. Since the library doesn't run in the Dalvik VM, the garbage collector won't free the resources. `AsyncTask` won't help here since this also runs in the same process as the rest of his application.